# Compiling for specific version of c runtime for windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, msvcrt

I have mobile device that, from all the msvcrXX files has msvcr80.dll. Visual studio compiles my library into one dependent on msvcr90.dll.

How can i change dependencies of my dll? I do not want to change runtime version on mobile device. Sure enough, problem can be avoided by compiling with /MT, but i am interested in solution, not avoidance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it possible only if You compile & link Your project against specific version of CRT libraries. Given version of VS has support for concrete version of these libs:
VS 2005 => msvcrt8
VS 2008 => msvcrt9

Std lib are linked against via #pragma comment(lib, "libcXXX.lib")
or #pragma comment(lib, "msvcXXX.lib")

depending on Your project configuration (look at afx.h)

There is no dependency definition for CruntimeLib in VCPROJ, so You have nothing to change in here.

If you get complete tree of required libs/dlls/headers in older version (8.0) for a concrete platform (example.: Win32 or PocketPC 2003, etc.)
You will need to change paths for a given platform in:

Tools / Options / Project and Solutions / VC++ Directories

(!!!ATTENTION backup Your config before via export operation from menu)